# ¿como introducir un valor en un array que contiene otros array dentro?

Tags: javascript-objeto, pentaho

estoy tratando de meter un valor a un array que se encuentra dentro de otro he tratado de utilizar el metodo push pero sin exito mi codigo es el siguiete

```
var data = [
  {
    x: [resultado[0][0],resultado[1][0]],
    y: [resultado[0][1],resultado[1][1]],
    type: 'bar'
  }
];
```

la cuestion es que quiero introducir el siguiente valor dentro de X o Y con push he intentado esto

```
data.push.x(resultado[2][0])
```

Pero sin exito alguno

si alguien puede ayudarme le agradeciria la verdad ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data es un arreglo de objetos, y a su ves sus propiedades "x" e "y", tienen un arreglo de 2 resultados si no me equivoco, verdad ?

```
  var data = [
      {
        x: [resultado[0][0],resultado[1][0]],
        y: [resultado[0][1],resultado[1][1]],
        type: 'bar'
      }
    ];
```

Lo que estas necesitando,es acceder a la posición Cero de data, la cual mostras en tu porción de código, acceder por la nomenclatura del punto a la propiedad, y como ya sabes, esa misma es un arreglo de la matriz que estés usando

> `data[0].x.push(resultado[2][0]);`

Ten cuidado porque aunque javascript sea poco tipado, y permisivo en cuanto a comenzar un arreglo vació, tienen que saber en que posición se encuentra al que tu quieras acceder.

Answer (score 1):

Tu variable data es un Array, concretamente un Array de objetos.

Para acceder al primer (y único) elemento que contiene, debes empezar con `data[0]`, a partir de ahí puedes acceder al objeto que se encuentra dentro, y concretamente quieres acceder a su variable X, lo cual nos deja con `data[0].x`.

En este punto estás seleccionando el Array que contiene la variable X del primer objeto de tu Array data. Ahí es cuando debes hacer el push():

`data[0].x.push(resultado[2][0]);`